# Importing JSONP data from HTML page then exporting to CSV

Tags: mysql, r, html-parsing, jsonp

I have some JSON data, of which this is a snippet:

```
{"sweater":"15", "localtime":"7:14 PM", "xcoord":-61, 
  "desc":"John Smith SHOT on Jack Jones", "teamid":10,"strength":701,
  "pid":8465200,"formalEventId":"TOR8", "period":1, "type":"Shot", "p3name":"",
   "eventid":8, "p2name":"Jack Jones", "ycoord":21, "pid3":"", "time":"00:38", 
   "playername":"John Smith", "p1name":"John Smith",
   "video":"2_26_ott_tor_0910_TOR8_save_800K_16x9.flv", "pid2":8469461, "pid1":8465200}
```

I would like to grab this info from an HTML URL with this format:

http://foo.com/data/20092010/20090xxxxx/PxP.jsonp

where xxxxx is a 5 digit game code which I would like to have inserted from a list (via loop).

The data I need most is: sweater, xcoord, teamid, strength, period, type, ycoord, time, playername AND to have the game code (xxxxx) inserted as a column as well.

So it would be:

Gamecode, sweater, xcoord, teamid, strength, period, type, ycoord, time, playername

Then, have it export all the info into one (1) CSV file.

Can anyone help with pointing me in right direction?

EDIT:

I tried to import the json file as a local file, using the following code:

```
#libraries
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)
library(bitops)

#fetch data
j <- getURL("file:///Desktop/test.jsonp")

#grab JSON
j.list <- fromJSON(j)

#get each data item
j.df <- data.frame(playername = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$sweater))
j.df <- data.frame(xcoord = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$xcoord))
j.df <- data.frame(ycoord = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$ycoord))
j.df <- data.frame(type = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$type))

write.csv(j.df, file="fooPxP.csv")
```

and get an empty CSV file. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is some of the actual data file from beginining:

```
loadPlayByPlay({"data":{"refreshInterval":0,"game":{"awayteamid":9,"awayteamname":"Ottawa Senators","hometeamname":"Toronto Maple Leafs","plays":{"play":[{"sweater":"11","localtime":"7:14 PM","xcoord":76,"desc":"Daniel Alfredsson HIT on Tomas Kaberle","teamid":9,"strength":701,"pid":8460621,"formalEventId":"TOR51","period":1,"type":"Hit","p3name":"","eventid":51,"p2name":"Tomas Kaberle","ycoord":-40,"pid3":"","time":"00:16","playername":"Daniel Alfredsson","p1name":"Daniel Alfredsson","pid2":8465200,"pid1":8460621},{"sweater":"15","localtime":"7:14 PM","xcoord":-61,"desc":"Tomas Kaberle SHOT on Pascal Leclaire","teamid":10,"strength":701,"pid":8465200,"formalEventId":"TOR8","period":1,"type":"Shot","p3name":"","eventid":8,"p2name":"Pascal Leclaire","ycoord":21,"pid3":"","time":"00:38","playername":"Tomas Kaberle","p1name":"Tomas Kaberle","video":"2_26_ott_tor_0910_TOR8_save_800K_16x9.flv","pid2":8469461,"pid1":8465200}}})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [an article](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/analysing-the-ismb-2010-meeting-using-r/) on fetching JSON from a URL and converting to a data frame, which might help you to get started.

You can fetch the data using getURL() in the RCurl library, like this:

```
library(RCurl)
j <- getURL("http://foo.com/data/20092010/20090xxxxx/PxP.jsonp")
```

Next, fromJSON() in the rjson package should convert it to a list:

```
library(rjson)
j.list <- fromJSON(j)
```

You can then construct a data frame from the list.  For example, to get a column named "sweater", try:

```
j.df <- data.frame(sweater = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$sweater))
```

Just add more columns as arguments to data.frame() using the other JSON keys.

To add the "xxxxx", you'll need to parse the URL using something like grep().

Once you have your data frame, you can write to CSV using either write.table() or write.csv().  For many URLs, you'll have to figure out how to combine the lists generated by fromJSON() into one data frame.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So for "strength" it would be: j.df <- data.frame(strength = sapply(j.list, function(x) x$strength))?

Comment: OK, so I tried this, got error and realized the URL I get the data from has this before the info: loadPlayByPlay -- how do I make it "skip" that? Or, instead of a URL can I import the info from text file?

Comment: I think you can pass the name of a text file to fromJSON(). Or, use one of the string processing functions in R to mung the URL into the correct form.

Comment: This "loadPlayByPlay" thing is the jsonp callback function - its a trick to enable cross-site scripting. Read up on the difference between json and jsonp. In R, use things like gsub or substr to cut out the bits you need. Its possible the target web site provides plain json though, via a different URL.

Comment: I edited my origanl Q with some of the code I am trying and a snipet of the actual JSON code, with how it begins. Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's R functions for reading anything from a URL (see help(download.file), and also the rjson package on CRAN for handling json data. Some tweaking may be needed if its really JSONP.

For a similar example, check out my geonames package - it reads JSON data from geonames.org and constructs data frames.

If its not on CRAN then its on R-Forge. I forget..

Answer (score 0):

**Writing file**
Writing a file in tn the client is problematic for most browsers due to security restrictions. 
In Internet Explorer only you can write a file using the execCommand - example in http://4umi.com/web/javascript/filewrite.php.

**Translating json to CSV**
I ran into this converted from json to csv.
http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/09/19/json-to-csv.aspx

**Alternative**
Generate the conversion on the server and download to the browser straight text (this is mime text/plain)